# Filter an array of strings with Matlab

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, filter

In Python, I could filter a list of strings `l` using `l = [k for k in l if 'ab' in k])`. What is the equivalent of this in Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a subpattern in each string in the array, you can do

```
l = l(contains(l, 'ab'));
```

Otherwise, if you want an exact match, it would be

```
l = l(strcmp(l, 'ab'));
```

Or `strcmpi` if you don't care about case.